# graphql-java nested resolvers are executed in different thread have different Spring security contexts

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, graphql-java

I am using graphql-java, and it executes the different nested resolvers in separate threads.

I have a custom filter on spring security that parses the Bearer token from the Authorization Header and adds that to the current spring security context.

I was temporarily able to solve the issue by listening to the ContextRefreshedEvent and forcing the strategy to Global, as you can see here:

```
    @EventListener
    fun setupSecurityContext(event: ContextRefreshedEvent) {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL)
    }
```

I am not happy with this solution because I have to access the tokens on the resolvers with a global static call when I would like to receive it passed as a parameter on the resolver.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication.principal
```

I believe this is not a good practice. I guess the data from one request can be exposed to another user by a different thread.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue using a retrofit client.
All I need is just to set spring delegating executor to the okhttp dispatcher like this:

```
@Bean
DelegatingSecurityContextExecutorService dispatcherExecutor() {
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutorService(
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new SynchronousQueue<>(), Util.threadFactory("OkHttp Dispatcher", false)
            )
    );
}

@Bean
OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    var interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(retrofitConnectionTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(retrofitConnectionTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .dispatcher(new Dispatcher(dispatcherExecutor()))
            .build();
}
```

What about graphql, please look at `graphql.execution.ExecutorServiceExecutionStrategy`. It allows to setup graphql async calls executor service, so you can pass spring delegating executor service here.